# (Alternative to) or (proper use of ) AndroidObservables in Activity

Tags: android, rx-java

I have been using `AndroidObservable`s for operations that need to happen off the UI thread.  I now find myself in this situation: I need to do an operation off the main thread, and then change the UI depending on the result.  My attempt looks like this:

```
subscription = AndroidObservable.bindActivity(this, Observable.just(null))
    .observeOn(Schedulers.io())
    .subscribe(new Action1<Object>() {
      @Override
      public void call(Object o) {
        if (doCheckThatMustBeOffMainThread()) {
          doSomethingWithTheUI();
        }
      }
    });
```

This is problematic because I’m now interacting with the UI off the main thread.

I’m using `AndroidObservable`s partially because I know (think?) that I can avoid memory leaks by unsubscribing `onDestroy()`, but given how contrived this use of `AndroidObservable` seems (creating an observable that emits null…) and my inability to interact with the UI on the main thread makes me think there is probably a more appropriate way of using `AndroidObservable`s—or an alternative method that is also safe from memory leaks.  What might these be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to move the check to its own Observable. That way you can control the scheduler it runs on.

```
Observable<Boolean> doCheckObservable =
        Observable
                .create(new Observable.OnSubscribe<Boolean>() {
                    @Override
                    public void call(Subscriber<? super Boolean> subscriber) {
                        // Runs on the io thread when subscribed to.
                        // Do check that returns true or false.
                        subscriber.onNext(doCheckThatMustBeOffMainThread());
                        subscriber.onCompleted();
                    }
                })
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io());

Subscription subscription =
        AndroidObservable
                .bindActivity(this, doCheckObservable)
                .subscribe(new Action1<Boolean>() {
                    @Override
                    public void call(Boolean doThatCheckPassed) {
                        if (doThatCheckPassed) {
                            // bindActivity() makes this run on the main thread.
                            doSomethingWithTheUI();
                        }
                    }
                });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// NOTE: This is now AppObservable in the latest RxAndroid release.
AndroidObservable.bindActivity(this, Observable.defer(
    new Func0<Observable<Void>>() {

      @Override
      public Observable<Void> call() {
        return doCheckThatMustBeOffMainThread() ?
            Observable.just(null) : Observable.empty();
      }

    })
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
    .subscribe(new Action1<Void>() {

      @Override
      public void call(Void unused) {
        doSomethingWithTheUi();
      }

    }));
```

This way you're still pushing null through an observable, but this time it's just being used as a signal, and the work happens where you need it to: the check out in io land, and the reaction on the UI thread.